# GIT: Get base and compare branches of a Pull Request (NOT api.github.com)

Tags: git, github, command-line, branch, pull-request

Is there any way to **get more details about pull request** using command line?

For example on github.com I've created Pull Requests from branch **A to dev** and from **B to dev**
How can I get details like:

```
[
    {title: 'First PR', from: 'A', base: 'dev'},
    {title: 'Second PR', from: 'B', base: 'dev'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is a command line utility that works with [api.github.com pull API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) *but only for 100 pull requests*

```
curl \
    https://api.github.com/repos/github/gitignore/pulls\?per_page\=100 \
| \
    jq "[ \
            .[] | { \
                title: .title, \
                from: .head.label, \
                to: .base.label \
            } \
        ]"
```

To get more than 100 pull request you would need to loop thru the [Link Header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header)